How to change path to the current directory in bash
I'm trying to customize my bash prompt and here's what looks perfect for me:
PS1='\n\[\033[32m\]\h \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n'

I want the current path to start only from parent directory, for example I want this:
username /e/dir1/_workspace/projectDir (master)

To be this:
username projectDir (master)

While projectDir is the main directory for my current project.
Also when I cd deeper I want the output to be relative to parent directory like this:
username projectDir/Dir_x/Dir_y (master)

Is there any way to achieve that?
I tried to use \W instead of \w but that only showed the current directory even if I cd deeper.
I also tried PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2 but this also didn't give me what I want.

Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [unix.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again). Having said that, we already have a fair number of Bash prompt customization questions here; please search before asking.

How do you know what is the "main directory for my project"? The directory is /projecta/projectb/projectc what should show up?

Maybe this will help. Try to break the parts down into smaller pieces.

How to print username?
How to print top level project dir?
How to print current project dir relative to top level?
How to print working dir (combination of top level and current dir)?
How to print the branch name?

Post suggests __git_ps1 which might imply an environment variable already exist. Also, the branch master (a git defalt value) suggest that maybe this is all centered around git.
If git isn't what you are seeking then the value in this post might be that it presents a recipe to create a solution given a tool that reports the variables specified, username, project dir, relative dir, and branch name.
function ps1_username() { echo "username"; }
function ps1_top_level() { basename $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel); }
function ps1_show_prefix() { git rev-parse --show-prefix; }
function ps1_working_dir() { echo $(ps1_top_level)/$(ps1_show_prefix); }
function ps1_branch() { git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD; }

PS1='\n\[\033[32m\]$(ps1_username)\n'

PS1='\n\[\033[33m\]$(ps1_top_level)\n'

PS1='\n\[\033[33m\]$(ps1_show_prefix)\n'

PS1='\n\[\033[33m\]$(ps1_working_dir)\n'

PS1='\n\[\033[36m\]$(ps1_branch)\n'

# ALL TOGETHER NOW
PS1='\n\[\033[32m\]$(ps1_username) \[\033[33m\]$(ps1_working_dir) \[\033[36m\]$(ps1_branch)\[\033[0m\]\n'

Expected Output:
username projectDir/Dir_x/Dir_y/ develop


This seems promising, assuming that "project dir" is definable as the root of a git project. I'm not sure why it was downvoted. But probably you should specify in the answer that it only works if that holds true - the root of the project is a git repository.

I suppose one concern is what happens when you are using bash outside of a git project - will that just crash your bash prompt?

adding disclaimer about git, hope it helps someone.

@xpt, the downvote button has hovertext. In absence of anything more explicit, that's your default reason.

Aside: function funcname() { merges legacy ksh and POSIX syntax in such a way as to be needlessly incompatible with both legacy ksh and the POSIX spec. Drop the function keyword to be compatible with POSIX, or drop the () to be (sorta) compatible with 1980s ksh. (Real ksh changes the semantics of function declaration based on which format is in use; bash doesn't honor that selection, arguably making the legacy syntax confusing to people who do know ksh).

There are many ways. My favorite (most powerful) is using power of PROMPT_COMMAND's variable. Having in mind that you can store dozens of .bashrc files put following stuff into one u use under ur git session:
export_dir_name () {
    export exported_dir=${PWD/`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/}
    # you might want to do smth more with value before exporting - it's up to u
}
export_ps1 () {
    export PS1="\[\033[32m\]\h \[\033[33m\]$exported_dir\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\] "
    unset exported_dir # you can throw away this line - it's up to u 
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND='export_dir_name && export_ps1'

You can set details according to your taste, I just want to show the direction:

export vars with basic tricks
pick them up in PS1
use PROMPT_COMMAND to be updated all the time ;)


PROMPT_COMMAND doesn't need to be exported and arguably shouldn't be: If a child-process shell inherits the PROMPT_COMMAND but doesn't inherit the functions it uses, it'll throw errors. Leave it as a regular shell variable, not an environment variable; that way, child processes can get it by running .bashrc themselves if they want to.

(PS1 doesn't need to be exported either, for the same reason; and I'd argue that you also have no good reason to export exported_dir -- why use up environment space, which comes from a limited per-process pool shared with command-line arguments, for something that would work perfectly well if stored on the heap instead?).

@CharlesDuffy you are problably right. My export comes from my .bashrc and its dependencies - highly customized. Although final shape is free to choose for @nabil-yasser.  Anyway - you pointed good advice.
